# Can I make a scatter/line chart without the x-axis?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scatter-plot, line-plot

I was trying to make a scatter or line chart without the x-axis in pyplot, matplotlib because it turns out I don't need an x-axis. But all google results show how to hide it not remove it.

I tried this approach to try:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

number = int(input('Which numbers ------ conjecture would you like to see? \n'))
y_points = []
x_points = []

def the_conjecture(num, y_lst, x_lst):
    while num != 1:
        y_lst.append(num)
        if num % 2 == 1:
            # odd
            num *= 3
            num += 1
        elif num % 2 == 0:
            # even
            num /= 2

    if num == 1:
        # appending 1
        y_lst.append(num)
    # creating an x_list full of i's
    for i in range(len(y_lst)):
        x_lst.append('i')

the_conjecture(number, y_points, x_points)
# turning all components from float to int
y_points = list(map(int, y_points))


plt.scatter(x_points, y_points)
plt.show()
```

but the result came to be:
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PcOvC.png) with input 4

Why am I getting only one x-column?

Is there some way to eliminate the x-axis from the process of making the chart?

Please tell me what to do.